# Changing the slug for custom post type resulted in 404 for single post type and pages

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-post-type, slug

My website have custom post type : products and tied to  custom taxonomy :  categories.

Currently my URLs for particular product is like this:

```
example.com/product/laptop/acer/acerproductname
```

As I wanted to remove the slug and URLs should look like this

```
example.com/laptop/acer/acerproductname
```

so to remove this, I changed the slug while registering custom post type.

from

```
$slug = product."/%product_category%/%product_brand%";
```

to

```
$slug = "/%product_category%/%product_brand%";
```

Now the post register function look like this

```js
 public function aw_register_post_type(){        
        // Labels
 $labels = array(
  'name' => __('Products','framework'),
  'singular_name' => __('Product','framework'),
  'add_new' => __('Add new','framework'),
  'add_new_item' => __('Add new product','framework'),
  'edit_item' => __('Edit','framework'),
  'new_item' => __('New product','framework'),
  'view_item' => __('View product','framework'),
  'search_items' => __('Search product','framework'),
  'not_found' =>  __('No product found','framework'),
  'not_found_in_trash' => __('No product found in trash','framework'), 
  'parent_item_colon' => '',
  'menu_name' => __('Products','framework')
 );
 
 $short_url = (get_option('tz_products_short_url') != '') ? get_option('tz_products_short_url') : 0;
 $slug_first_part = ((get_option('tz_custom_products_slug') != '') ? get_option('tz_custom_products_slug') : 'product');
 if($short_url == 1) {
  $slug = $slug_first_part;
  
 } else {
  $slug = "/%product_category%/%product_brand%";

 }
 $rewrite = array( 
            'slug'          => $slug,
   //'with_front'    => false 
);
 
 // Arguments
 $args = array(
  'labels' => $labels,
  'public' => true,
  'publicly_queryable' => true,
  'show_ui' => true, 
  'show_in_menu' => true, 
  'query_var' => true,
  'menu_icon' => get_stylesheet_directory_uri().'/img/admin/admin-products.png',
  'rewrite' => true,
  'capability_type' => 'post',
  //'rewrite' => array("slug" => $slug), // Permalinks format
  'rewrite' => $rewrite,
  'has_archive' => true, 
  'hierarchical' => false,
  'menu_position' => null,
  'taxonomies' => array('post_tag'),
  'supports' => array('title','editor','author','thumbnail','excerpt', 'comments', 'tags')
 );
```

Now the URLs for custom post type is exactly what I wanted that is

```
 example.com/laptop/acer/acerproductname
```

**Main Problem**

After changing the slug my blogs and other pages now showing 404 error. What can be the possible reason and what can be the possible solution for this.

Comment: Does It work if you uncomment 'with_front' => false? Do you make flush_rewrite_rules() after changes?

Comment: Uncommenting does not make any difference. No i did not.

Comment: Flushed it still no difference

Answer (score -1):

Try adding this into your functions.php

```
flush_rewrite_rules();
```

Comment it out once you've refreshed the page.

Comment: already tried it. No use. as discussed with some other dev. He said need to add another rewrite rules line in functions.php